# what does the following syntax in php mean?

Tags: php, associative-array

I am working on fixing some bug in legacy php code. I am not a PHP person. so please bear with me if this is a stupid question.

I see this line in the code:

```
$credentials = array("username"=>$fields->username, "password"=>$fields->password);
$this->profile->create($fields);
```

I don't understand what this syntax for array means?

I know this is associate array:

`array("username"=>"mike","password"=>"123"`)
will translate to

```
{  
"username": "mike",
"password" : "123"
}
```

but what the above one will translate to?

Comment: Do you mean: `$fields->username` ? Or do you mean the second line?

Comment: RTFM please: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: You say `{...}` in your question, but more correct is to say `[...]`, as it is an array, and not just any object.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you used for the example, `$fields` is an object. Then, `username` is a variable or property of the object. So, you end up with the array:

```
{
    "username": $fields->username,
    "password": $fields->password
}
```

If you are confused by the arrow syntax for objects, read the documentation on using objects for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

`$this` refers to the current instance of the class that this code is in.

`profile` refers to the class member profile, which itself is an instance of some class.

`create` is a function in that class, and is now being invoked.

The variable `$fields` is being passed as an argument to the function.